# Toolbar of NSScrollView inside SplitView

Tags: cocoa, nsscrollview

I am new to Cocoa development and I've been trying to use a NSScrollView (Rich Document Content Text View) with a SplitView but the toolbar of the text editor is always placed above the SplitView:
[image]

I cannot find a way to have it be placed inside of the right panel. Do I have to add additional components to accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: How are the controls added to the view?

Comment: Using the storyboard, I've tried changing their properties but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Can't you move the controls to the pane?

Comment: If by controls you mean the toolbar of the NSScrollView, I cannot, I only see the text area when I move it (the are below the save button), I only see the toolbar when I run the program.